# Force IOC to create new object on every invocation

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am injecting an object using IOC, but due to internal caching in the object I want to ensure a fresh instance of the object every time it's invoked. The bellow code works for creating the instance the first time, but it seems to hold on to the instance and is reusing it for subsequent calls

```
_container = new WindsorContainer().Install(
    FromAssembly.Containing<RepositoryInstaller>());

_container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

_container.Register(
    Component.For<Func<MyUnitOfWork>>()
        .Instance(() => {  
            return _container.Resolve<MyUnitOfWork>(); 
        }).LifeStyle.Transient);
```

What I want is to be able to call the resolved Func instance but have the IOC container provide me with a new instance of MyUnitOfWork every time:

```
//invoke FUNC and ensure that instance of MyUnitOfWork is created every time
var newInstance = myInstance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from you question whether you want the func to be a new instance each time, or if you want the unit of work to be a new instance each time.

If it's the former, I can't see how it would matter as the instance would have no state.

If it's the latter, can you show the code where you register MyUnitOfWork in the container (probably in RepositoryInstaller)?  I'm guessing you're not registering that with a transient lifestyle.  It looks like the Func is what you are registering as transient in the code shown (not the MyUnitOfWork itself).

Edit: based on your edit, my best guess is you are not registering the MyUnitOfWork as Transient.  This line appears to be registering the **Func** as transient:

```
_container.Register(Component.For<Func<MyUnitOfWork>>().Instance(() 
=> {  return _container.Resolve<MyUnitOfWork>(); }).LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Can you show the RepositoryInstaller code?